# How will you find area of quadrilateral.?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

If we are given four points in coordinate geometry. After finding the length joining these four points  like as AB, Bc, CA, AD. If a Quadrilateral is formed by these sides and length of these sides are unequal then,how will u find the area of quadrilateral?

Comment: You cannot compute area only from side lengths.

Comment: i think you will need Bretschneider's formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral

Comment: Actually, you don't need to compute the side lengths: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula

Comment: @achillehui: anyway, I do not think such approach is really efficient, especially compared to just plugging in eight numbers in the shoelace formula.